# Sql server round my decimal data

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, rounding

Sql data type is money, .Net data type is decimal. I send 1.8714 to sql for insert data but sql server round it to 1.8700. How can I save my data? And how do I send without rounding?

Comment: Are you sending the data with or without the separator in it?

Comment: Please be clear in terms of what you mean by "1,8714" - is that "between 1 and 2" or "a bit less than twenty thousand"?

Comment: SQL Server will store 4 decimals in a MONEY column.  How are you saving the values? (add to your question, don't respond in a comment)

Comment: @cagin: Edited your question to use culture en-us (or [invariantculture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)) according to the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my varable type decimal to float on .Net side and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table <tablename> alter column <columnname> float
```

Comment: may be numeric(19,4) would be better.